# Can manipulate multiple windows in Xvfb simultaneously

Tags: selenium, xvfb

I'm using Xvfb + Selenium standalone server to do some webpage testing. I have multiple remote web drivers(threads) to send request to selenium server, but looks like if multiple testings run in parallel, the performance is much slower than that of running tests one by one.

1. Does Xvfb has restriction on the number of windows that can be opened, say firefox windows/instances?
2. If two firefox windows are running inside Xvfb, can these two windows be manipulated at same time, say clicking a link on the page? As we know, on a desktop display, only the most top window can be manipulated, like clicking and entering something on the page.
3. Do I need to setup a Xvfb process for each selenium test to get better performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `Jenkins`? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin  - will setup virtual screens for all your tests

Comment: No. I'm using my own code in Java to send test requests to selenium standalone server. I'm wondering how Xvfb handles the actions for multiple firefox windows at same time.

Comment: Why are you not using [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) ?
Question 2: IMO you can run into problems with selenium when the browser looses focus.

Comment: @VolkerK, We cannot use Selenium Grid for some reason. Even using Selenium Grid still has this issue, Grid server just redirects the request to selenium node server(also includes load balance), with heavy work load, I think each single selenium node server may have multiple sessions to run test in Xvfb. Yes, I knew that some guys raise the issue when browser loose focus.